# How exactly the hidden state works in an RNN ? How to decide on how many past instances to consider?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, rnn

I am unable to grasp the working of RNN because in different tutorials, it is explained differently.

Please correct me as I have considered that:

In a `Many to one Model`: if a sentence is like `My name is Shady` becomes `Mon nom Shady` then how are the inputs were fed to model? IMO it was that `My` produced `Mon` by multiplying with `w0` and produced some hidden state as `h1` by multiplying with `a0`. Then (`h1` * `a1`)+ (`name` * `w1`) produced the `nom`. **I want to ask that how is the state `h` changing? is `h_i` at the ith time a single float that the i+1_th input will use? If so,then why do they say that it uses  previous `N` states when it is using a `cumulative function of all the previous states` that have already occured???**

**And if the sentence is paragraph of 10000 words, will the last input use `cumulative function state` which is a state defined by all the previous 9999 inputs??**